# Rails link_to_add failing on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Buttons generated by link_to_add are clickable but no partial form is generated for them on the screen after being clicked.  The issue started after adding the modal.js from bootstrap.  Currently the javascript is loaded using:

In the layout, along with:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1.4' 
gem 'nested_form'
```

In the gem file, using rails 3.0.9.

Locally using development mode there is no issue, the issue only arises once pushed to Heroku.

Tracing what's happening I see no errors occuring in any javascript, but I do notice that this happens at the bottom of any source involving add_to_link:

```
<div data-blueprint="&lt;div class=&quot;fields&quot;&gt;   &lt;div class=&quot;w450 eboxw&quot;&gt;
    &lt;table style=&quot;width:100%;&quot; class=&quot;copy reg&quot;&gt;
     &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td&gt;&lt;label class=&quot;copy
```

I believe that this is meant to be the target of the link_to_add action and the fact that it contains so many seemingly incorrect characters is troubling to me.

I've read about asset pipelines which I don't believe I have set up for the application, any configuration tips or possible reasons this could happen are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to precompile the assets before uploading to Heroku. Did you do that? Can you use Rails 3.2, then precompile, then upload?